# Почему блок не выравнивается по центру?

Tags: html, css, css3

Приветствую. Не могу понять почему блок `pagination` не центрируется.. Не исключаю, что все должно быть очевидно, но что-то пока не нахожу в чем причина

```css
.pagination {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-holder">
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/ .pagination-->
</div>
<!--/ .pagination-holder-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align:center;`

```css
.pagination {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-holder">
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/ .pagination-->
</div>
<!--/ .pagination-holder-->
```

Comment: спасибо! а можно подробнее почему `text-align:center;` зависит от `display: block;` ? И кстати, в моем случае сработала только связка: `.pagination-holder {text-align:center;} .pagination {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: `text-align:center;` в данном случае влияет на `.pagination li {display: inline-block;}`, то есть НЕ на блочный элемент. я не очень понимаю что вы имеете ввиду в комментарии, но в моем примере можно нажать на кнопку `ВЫПОЛНИТЬ КОД` и увидеть, что все работает и без `.pagination-holder {text-align:center;} .pagination {display: inline-block;}`

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что `div."pagination"` - это блочный элемент, который автоматически растягивается на всю длину родителя. Нельзя выровнять блок внутри другого блока, если у них одинаковая ширина (максимальная по горизонтали), поэтому для того, чтобы выровнять его по центру, нужно указать его фиксированную ширину `width` или `max-width`, тогда и сработает `margin: 0 auto`.

Answer (score 1):

А почему не так?

Кстати, тегам `<div>` прописывать стиль `display: block;` не нужно, он по умолчанию таким и является.

```css
.pagination ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-holder">
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/ .pagination-->
</div>
<!--/ .pagination-holder-->
```

Comment: Ну я б не сказал, что прям совсем не нужно, практика хорошая, ибо бывают моменты, когда `div` инлайновый, по какой-то причине, а ты ему бац и `block` уже прописал :)